# Which of the following conditions imply that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx = \int_0^1\ f(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis

let $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of non-negative continuous functions defined
on $[0, 1]$. Assume that $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ for every $x ∈ [0, 1].$ Which of the
following conditions imply that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f_n(x)dx =  \int_0^1\ f(x) dx$$

$a.$ $f_n(x) ↑ f(x)$ for every $x ∈ [0, 1].$

$b.$ $f_n(x) ≤ f(x)$ for every $x ∈ [0, 1]$

$c.$ $f$ is continuous

option  c) will be False  take  $f_n(x) = nxe^{-nx^2}$

As im  confusing  about  option $a)$  and option $b)$

Any hints/solution

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: Check Beppo Levi's monotone convergence theorem and Dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Monotone convergence theorem and Fatou's lemma.